# Delete an instance of class using mechanize in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mechanize

I am using mechanize to deal with a form . I have parsed the form using mechanize and the output comes is as follows:

```
{forms
 #<Mechanize::Form
 {name nil}
 {method "POST"}
 {action "/dashboard/checks/50114dbeae6f61b428000ad8"}
 {fields
  [hidden:0x60c476a type: hidden name: _method value: put]
  [text:0x60c4616 type: text name: check[name] value: Testing]
  [text:0x60c4512 type: text name: check[url] value: http://www.pintile.com]
  [text:0x60c445e type: text name: check[interval] value: 120]
  [text:0x60c435a type: text name: check[maxTime] value: 1500]
  [textarea:0x60c4116 type:  name: check[tags] value: ]}
 {radiobuttons}
 {checkboxes}
 {file_uploads}
 {buttons
  [button:0x60c3d88 type: submit name:  value: ]
  [button:0x60c3d24 type: submit name: delete value: ]
```

There are 2 buttons in this form
**Save Changes**(1st), **Delete**(2nd), 
I use the following code to save the changes and it works fine:

```
form.field_with(:name => "check[name]").value = "Testing"
button = form.buttons.first
agent.submit(form, button)
```

The changes are saved successfully. But when i try to delete using the code below it does not work:

```
button = form.buttons.first
agent.submit(form, button)
```

It does nothing. Please help me out to get over with this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the website is a typical rails form, the delete button is most likely a JavaScript action. Mechanize does not support JavaScript. You may want to use something like capybara with the web kit driver instead, which has full JavaScript support and all of the functionality you already have in mechanize.

Comment: Hey Tanzeeb, I am really thankful your response. You are correct **delete** button is a javascript action. Now i want to trigger that javascript function. I looked for [link](https://github.com/thoughtbot/capybara-webkit) but this is for testing. Suggest me more please.

Comment: Here's a good example to get your started: http://www.chadcf.com/blog/using-capybara-javascript-capable-replacement-mechanize

Answer (score 0):

The code snippet below work well with link.Have you tried click

```
agent.get("http://your url")

agent.page.link_with(:text => "link name").click
```

Give it a try..
Else as mentioned above you can use Capybara

Comment: The problem is its not a link so click does not work on it. It is triggered by a javascript function.

Answer (score 0):

Delete is the last button. Therefore you want:

```
button = form.buttons.last
agent.submit(form, button)
```

or more simply:

```
form.submit form.buttons.last
```

Answer (score 0):

If Mechanize is good enough for you and you do not require any javascript support that would bring Capybara, you should be able to emulate what the Javascript does. In this case, the source would be needed to better know what append, but I guess the value of the hidden field `_method` is replaced by `delete` prior the submit.